# C# is probably not the best choice for a security application?

Tags: c#, c++, security, winapi, api

I have stumbled in this phrase in the web:

> C# is probably not the best choice for a system-level application like
>   this. I believe plain C++ is much better here as you will need to do
>   lots of low-level API calls.

I was searching about security programs made using C#, like firewall, parental control, anti-virus, anti-spyware, etc.

So, is true that C# is probably not the best choice for a security application?

[edit]
I was researching about c# security programs, and I found 2 programs:
1) **Keepass** (http://keepass.info/compare.html) an impressive password manager that is migrating from c++ to c# !!!
2) **Home Again** (http://www.codeplex.com/totty530) is a packet sniffer made using c#
[/edit]

Comment: “System-level” != “security”. Also, you can write insecure programs in any language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Things like firewalls often need hooks into kernel-level facilities which aren't (trivially) exposed by managed runtimes like .NET. You can jump through hoops to use the C# language to do this sort of thing, but then, well, you'd be jumping through hoops.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you work in security, you probably want a gun.  C++ is a better gun than C#, but beware - it is much easier to shoot yourself in the foot with C++.

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing a firewall or anti-virus software as in your example, it is easier to write it in C++ since it can gain access to things that C# was not made for. C# is more secure than C++ for writing applications though since it is harder to mess things up.

Answer (score 4):

C# implies that you are using the .Net framework. That adds a lot of code to your application that you have very little control over. If there is a security risk in that version of .Net, it's now in your app.

The same may be true for any additional frameworks you employ with C++, but it is also possible to write C++ code without any additional frameworks.

Neither way defends against you adding insecure code though.

Comment: "If there is a security risk in that version of .Net, it's now in your app"  ---> I believe that is rare .net versions with security problems... but there is that possibility

Comment: It is rare - but if I were building something that I was being marketed on its superior security, relying on 3rd party libraries becomes a liability. Regardless of who provided them.

Answer (score 2):

Agree. Many of the functions that you'd want to call would be functions that you'd have to P/Invoke from C#. Callbacks from the OS to your C# program aren't pretty either, with stuff like System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.

Now, for stuff like the aforementioned Password Managers, this might not matter much. That's really just a fancy database, with smart import/export/storage/transformation features. Still, it would be useful if they could interact with other programs. You simply cannot inject a C# DLL in random processes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at **C++/CLI**. It will offer the conveniences of .NET, yet provide the low level access you may need with C++.

Answer (score 1):

.Net applications, out of the box, are fully reversible to readable code.(try it out: http://www.reflector.net/) Only the comments in the code are lost! ;) If it matters whether people can look easily under the hood of your application. You would be safer with C/C++ as its a little harder to reverse engineer. But .Net obfuscators or packers for your C/C++ application can make revers engineering on your applications alot harder. Hence it is never impossible. But be ware. Some .Net obfuscators do not handle SOAP WSDL services in your code well and cause errors by just obfuscating your code!